# AngularJS Bootstrap Typehead function not showing properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap UI typhead to make an auto complete. My code is working fine. but the problem is that it is not showing result properly in dropdown.
See this
[image]

See in above image, it's giving result in dropdown but unable to see the text.
I'm doing this in Asp MVC. here is my `cshtml` code.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/AutoCompleteDemo.js"></script>
</head>


    <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-controller="myCtrl" class="row-fluid">
                <form class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                         Code <input type="text" ng-model="selectedCode" />
                    City <input type="text" typeahead-on-select="setcode($item)" ng-model="selected" typeahead="Cityx.CityName for Cityx in City | filter:$viewValue" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and below is my JS code

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.selected = '';
        $scope.City = [
                    { code: 'JP', CityName: 'Jaipur' },
                    { code: 'DL', CityName: 'Delhi' },
                    { code: 'CHE', CityName: 'Chennai' },
                    { code: 'MUM', CityName: 'Mumbai' },
                    { code: 'KOL', CityName: 'Kolkata' },
                    { code: 'MAS', CityName: 'Chennai' },
                    { code: 'JAM', CityName: 'Jammu' },
                    { code: 'MAS', CityName: 'Chennai' },
                    { code: 'KAN', CityName: 'Kanpur' },
        ];
        $scope.setcode = function (site) {
            $scope.selectedCode = site.code;
        };
});
```

See It in Plunker, it's working fine.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gV8Bgk0TatGwJnqLGHcM?p=preview)**

Comment: to me it makes no sense to use name of main array as component names in the typahead options. Also you seem to be missing the `as` part of the query. See docs example. I suggest you create a  plunker demo

Comment: did you try putting an `as` part in? The syntax is the same as `ng-options` for `select` tags. Also need to adjust the filter part for the proprty to filter

Comment: Same code is working in Plunker.
http://plnkr.co/edit/gV8Bgk0TatGwJnqLGHcM?p=preview